# How to get column values in one comma separated value

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which contains rows like below

```
ID  User      Department
1   User1     Admin
2   User1     Accounts
3   User2     Finance
4   User3     Sales
5   User3     Finance
```

I need a select query which results following format

```
ID  User      Department
1   User1     Admin,Accounts
2   User2     Finance
3   User3     Sales, Finance
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You tagged the question with both sql-server and plsql so I will provide answers for both SQL Server and Oracle.

In SQL Server you can use `FOR XML PATH` to concatenate multiple rows together:

```
select distinct t.[user],
  STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ' + t1.department
         from yourtable t1
         where t.[user] = t1.[user]
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,2,'') department
from yourtable t;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f3a79/1/0).

In Oracle 11g+ you can use `LISTAGG`:

```
select "User",
  listagg(department, ',') within group (order by "User") as departments
from yourtable
group by "User"
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7119a/1)

Prior to Oracle 11g, you could use the `wm_concat` function:

```
select "User",
  wm_concat(department) departments
from yourtable
group by "User"
```

Comment: sqlfiddle.com doesn't seems to work. It looks like the domain expired in 2017, so it doesn't look like it's likely to ever work again, even though Google still brings it up and a couple other sites reference it. Maybe use db-fiddle.com? It's the first option I found for replacement.

Comment: Thanks for solution. Worked fine for me.

Comment: SQL Server 2017 added the STRING_AGG function, see this answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/69751057/1197553

Comment: I need the opposite to be done :-)

Answer (score 13):

In Sql Server you can use it.

```
DECLARE @UserMaster TABLE( 

    UserID INT NOT NULL, 

    UserName varchar(30) NOT NULL 

); 

INSERT INTO @UserMaster VALUES (1,'Rakesh')

INSERT INTO @UserMaster VALUES (2,'Ashish')

INSERT INTO @UserMaster VALUES (3,'Sagar')

SELECT * FROM @UserMaster

DECLARE @CSV VARCHAR(MAX) 

SELECT @CSV = COALESCE(@CSV + ', ', '') + UserName from @UserMaster 

SELECT @CSV AS Result
```

Comment: clean and simple :)

Comment: Thanks for saving my time, Appreciate it.

Comment: Very simple and useful. Thank you so much.

Comment: COALESCE is not an aggregate function, when grouped by ID and User you will COALESECE(Department + ',','') will throw the error Department it is not contained in an aggregate function

Comment: Use STRING_AGG function if SQL Server 2017 or later, see answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/69751057/1197553

Answer (score 11):

MYSQL:  To get column values as one comma separated value use  `GROUP_CONCAT( )` function as

```
GROUP_CONCAT(  `column_name` )
```

for example

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(  `column_name` ) 
FROM  `table_name` 
WHERE 1 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: If you have other columns before group_concat, then you need to add a 'group by' clause and mention them in the group by clause.

Answer (score 10):

You can do this with the following SQL:

```
SELECT STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT ',' + s.FirstName 
        FROM Employee s
        ORDER BY s.FirstName FOR XML PATH('')
    ),
     1, 1, ''
) AS Employees
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following Query:

```
select distinct Users,
 STUFF(
        (
        select ', ' + d.Department FROM @temp d
        where t.Users=d.Users
group by d.Department for xml path('')
        ), 1, 2, '') as Departments
 from @temp t
```

### Implementation:

```
Declare @temp Table(
ID int,
Users varchar(50),
Department varchar(50)
)
insert into @temp
(ID,Users,Department)
values
(1,'User1','Admin')
insert into @temp
(ID,Users,Department)
values
(2,'User1','Accounts')
insert into @temp
(ID,Users,Department)
values
(3,'User2','Finance')
insert into @temp
(ID,Users,Department)
values
(4,'User3','Sales')
insert into @temp
(ID,Users,Department)
values
(5,'User3','Finance')

 select distinct Users,
 STUFF(
        (
        select ', ' + d.Department FROM @temp d
        where t.Users=d.Users
group by d.Department for xml path('')
        ), 1, 2, '') as Departments

 from @temp t
```

### Result will be:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @UserMaster TABLE(
    UserID INT NOT NULL,    
    UserName varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    Department varchar(30) NOT NULL
);



INSERT INTO @UserMaster VALUES (1,'User1', 'Admin')
INSERT INTO @UserMaster VALUES (2,'User1', 'Accounts')
INSERT INTO @UserMaster VALUES (3,'User2', 'Finance')
INSERT INTO @UserMaster VALUES (1,'User3', 'Sales')
INSERT INTO @UserMaster VALUES (2,'User3', 'Finance')

SELECT UserName, String_Agg(Department, ',') as Department 
FROM @UserMaster
group by UserName
```

Answer (score 1):

**For Mysql:**

```
SELECT t.user, 

(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( t1.department ) FROM table_name t1 WHERE t1.user = t.user)department

FROM table_name t
GROUP BY t.user
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT( section ) 
FROM  `tmp` 
GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be easy to you. I am using group_concat which concatenate diffent values with separator as we have defined

```
select ID,User, GROUP_CONCAT(Distinct Department order  by Department asc 

separator ', ') as Department from Table_Name   group by ID
```

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle versions which does not support the WM_CONCAT, the following can be used

```
  select "User", RTRIM(
     XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT(e, department||',') ORDER BY department).EXTRACT('//text()') , ','
     ) AS departments 
  from yourtable 
  group by "User"
```

This one is much more powerful and flexible - you can specify both delimiters and sort order within each group as in **listagg**.

Answer (score 0):

(SELECT STUFF((
SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), column Name)
FROM TBALE NAME
FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')) as COLUMN NAME

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?