# single record with comma separated value

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using the sql query like

```
SELECT fun_systemuser(UserID) as ConsultantName,
       fun_store(UserID) as StoreName,
       count(UserID) as No_of_PhoneModel,
       PhoneModelID,
       (select LeegraRegion 
          from store 
         where ID=claim.StoreID) as Region,
       fun_network(UserID) as ChannelName,
       fun_group(claim.StoreID) as GroupName,
       fun_campaigns(UserID) as CampaignName  
  FROM `claim` 
 where UserID IN (SELECT id 
                    FROM `systemuser` 
                   WHERE `RoleID`=1 
                     and `Topconsultant`=1) 
   and StatusID=5 
 group by UserID ,PhoneModelID
```

I have query result like given below:

[image]

There are 4 records for single consultant with different phone model id and no. of sales of phone model id.

I want to single record for every consultant name and there should be show phone model and no.of phone model with comma separated value.

Ex. single record should display like below

```
Thomson 4U-Sunnypark 3,2,3,1  1,3,6,9 Pretoria Vodacom Sachar Mobile vodacom Campaigns
```

Is anybody know what should I use in query so I can get the result as I want.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15742716/how-to-get-column-values-in-one-comma-separated-value

Comment: Use string concatenation to concatenate the fields, e.g. `||` or `CONCAT`.

Comment: You forgot to mention the DBMS you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You must use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). For example:

```
  SELECT ConsultantName,
         StoreName,
         GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT No_of_Phonemodel SEPARATOR ',') ,
         GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT PhoneModelID SEPARATOR ',') ,
         Region
    FROM (
           SELECT fun_systemuser(UserID) as ConsultantName,
                  fun_store(UserID) as StoreName,
                  count(UserID) as No_of_PhoneModel,
                  PhoneModelID,
                  (select LeegraRegion 
                     from store 
                    where ID=claim.StoreID) as Region,
                  fun_network(UserID) as ChannelName,
                  fun_group(claim.StoreID) as GroupName,
                  fun_campaigns(UserID) as CampaignName  
             FROM `claim` 
            where UserID IN (SELECT id 
                               FROM `systemuser` 
                              WHERE `RoleID`=1 
                                and `Topconsultant`=1) 
              and StatusID=5 
            group by UserID ,PhoneModelID
         ) as S
GROUP BY ConsultantName,
         StoreName,
         Region
```

Comment: You forgot to add the `GROUP BY` clause

Comment: Oscar Pérez i can not use the GROUP_CONCAT for count(...) value.
I have updated my question and put the actual query now can you please help me?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I guess you could use my query changing the `table` with your whole query... If you can create an sqlfiddle with your data, we could try....

Comment: Thanks for your help but i have still issue with getting comma separate value for count value.When i use the Group contact with those value then it gives error like "#1111 - Invalid use of group function".
I am using like GROUP_CONCAT(count( PhoneModelID)  SEPARATOR ',') then it will give error.

Comment: I edited the answer. Could you please try it?