# Using SQL cursor for displaying data from database

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, cursors

I am making C# Windows Form Application, and it is connected to database.
Theme is: **Bookshop**.

In one of application's forms, there is DataGridView, which displays information about every book in shop.
In database, one book is unique, with its ISBN, and different books, in that context, can have same name.
Also, books can have many authors.
Meaning, when I make query that displays all books, it lists same book more than one time, to display all authors from that book.
What I want is, of course, to list all authors in one column, in one line, for one book.

I have been told that this could be done with cursors.
But, I can't imagine how to use them.
I don't want exact code, I just need some guidelines to solve this problem.

Also, is there maybe a better way to do this, then to use cursors?

Comment: I would suggest not to use cursors as they might cause performance degrade issues while you query in DB. I will recommend to use LINQ to SQL or StoredProcedure to get the results from DB. The actual solution will depend on your class structure.

Comment: You can take help from here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/63715/BookStore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FOR XML
```

Is the way to get a column into a comma separated list normally:

[How to get column values in one comma separated value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15742716/how-to-get-column-values-in-one-comma-separated-value)

Obviously it doesn't have to be a comma separating them, you could put CHAR(13) or whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a finished code example how you could do it (also with stuff as already suggested by others). Is it that what you were looking for?

```
-- declare variables

declare @ParamterCurrencyAmount numeric(26, 2),
        @ParameterRollingVisitSum int


-- declare table variable

declare @Books table
(
    ISBN int not null primary key,
    BookName varchar(255) not null
)

-- declare table variable

declare @Authors table
(
    AuthorID int primary key not null,
    AuthorName varchar(255) not null
)

-- declare table variable

declare @BookAuthorRelations table
(
    BookAuthorRelations int not null primary key,
    ISBN int not null,
    AuthorID int not null
)


-- insert sample data 

insert into @Books
(
    ISBN,
    BookName
)
select 1000, 'Book A' union all
select 2000, 'Book B' union all
select 3000, 'Book C'

insert into @Authors
(
    AuthorID,
    AuthorName
)
select 1, 'Jack' union all
select 2, 'Peter' union all
select 3, 'Donald'

insert into @BookAuthorRelations
(
    BookAuthorRelations,
    ISBN,
    AuthorID
)
select 1, 1000, 1 union all
select 2, 1000, 2 union all
select 3, 1000, 3 union all
select 4, 2000, 1 union all
select 5, 2000, 2 union all
select 6, 3000, 1


-- get books (with stuff)

select distinct Books.BookName,
stuff(
        (
            select distinct ', ' + Authors.AuthorName
            from @Authors Authors,
            @BookAuthorRelations BookAuthorRelations
            where BookAuthorRelations.AuthorID = Authors.AuthorID
            and Books.ISBN = BookAuthorRelations.ISBN
            for xml path(''), type
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    , 1, 2,'') data
from @Books Books
```

Comment: I think this is it :) I will look at it later.

Comment: Yes this is the same approach I was suggesting.  Just for information - the STUFF keyword is not the important part of this technique, that's just a clean way of removing the leading comma and space. (though in the above code snippet it needs changing to STUFF(... ,1,2,'')

Comment: George Dando thanks for clarification that STUFF is not the important part. I added STUFF(... ,1,2,'') to my sample to remove remove the leading ",".

Answer (score 0):

If you´re working on an Oracle-DB, you might use the LISTAGG - function like this:

```
SELECT listagg(a.author_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY b.isin) names 
  FROM books b
  join book_authors ba on ba.bookId = b.bookId
  join authors a on a.authorId = ba.authorid
```

Comment: What is your exact requirement? You want to use Cursor or not? As I told in my earlier comment use stored procedure.

Comment: Ok, but here you´ll find a LISTAGG-equivalent for SQL-Server http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver