# SQL - List of a field from a GROUP BY

Tags: sql

I have to write an SQL query and I am using the following SQL tables :

```
diet (id, name)
id : primary key

patient (id, familyname, firstname)
id : primary key

choice (idpatient, iddiet, optionnal, medical)
idpatient, iddiet : primary key
idpatient : foreign key in ref. to id from patient
idregime : foreign key in ref. to id from diet
```

medical the diet is mandatory (true)
optional the diet is a wish (true)

I need to write a SQL query to select for each patient (id, familyname, firstname), the list of diets (name) and for each of them the mention medical or optional.

I have started in writing this query but I know a GROUP BY should have all the fields mentioned in the SELECT also mentioned in the GROUP BY. So I could not add the fields from the diets name or the selection (medical / wish).

```
SELECT p.idpatient AS “id”, p.familyname AS “name”, p.firstname AS “firstname”
FROM choice AS c
INNER JOIN diet AS r
ON r.id = c.iddiet
INNER JOIN patient AS p
ON c.idpatient = p.id
GROUP BY p.idpatient, p.familyname, p.firstname
ORDER BY p.familyname, p.firstname
```

How can I go further using a GROUP BY?
Maybe I should not use a GROUP BY but only JOINS.

Sorry I am lost.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: It would also be helpful if you can add an example of the output you want.  See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: hello, thank you for your feedback. That is an exercise from school we are supposed to do on paper. So we need to follow SQL rules despite some SGBD such as MYSQL are more permisive. The input asked in the exercise in this order : I need to write a SQL query to select for each patient (id, familyname, firstname), the list of diets (name) and for each of them the mention medical or optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL and SQLite this is possible using GROUP_CONCAT() like this

```
SELECT p.idpatient AS id,p.familyname AS family_name, p.firstname AS first_name,
GROUP_CONCAT( d.name ) AS diets
FROM  choice AS c
INNER JOIN diet AS d
ON d.id = c.iddiet
INNER JOIN patient AS p
ON c.idpatient = p.id
GROUP BY p.idpatient, p.familyname, p.firstname
ORDER BY p.familyname, p.firstname
```

This idea is taken from [How to get column values in one comma separated value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15742716/how-to-get-column-values-in-one-comma-separated-value/20116757) - Here you can also find examples for other DBMS products.

You can test the behavior of GROUP_CONCAT() by running the following statements on https://sqliteonline.com/

```
INSERT INTO demo (ID,Name,Hint) 
VALUES(21,'SQL Online','Test for GROUP_CONCAT')
```

```
SELECT Name,GROUP_CONCAT( hint ) AS hints
FROM  demo 
GROUP BY name
```